# Is it possible to es6 import a commonjs module?

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-modules

I have a commonjs module, which was generated by Typescript 3.3.3.

Is it possible to use it with an es6 import statement? Here's what I have tried.

The generated module exports CountUp like this at the end of the file:

```
exports.CountUp = CountUp;
```

In my main.js:

```
import { CountUp } from './js/countUp.js';
```

And in index.html:

```
  <script src="./js/countUp.js"></script>
  <script src="./main.js" type="module"></script>
```

But I get

> countUp.js:13 Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
>       at countUp.js:13

*(Note: countUp.js is now distributed as an es6 module)*

Comment: MDN says it should be. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Browser_compatibility

Comment: I also think you want it to generate the file like one of these `export class CountUp {}` or `export function CoutUp(){}` What does you `tsconfig.json` look like?

Comment: Your `countUp` code seems not to check whether `exports` exists before attempting the CommonJS export.

Comment: @Pointy it does all that, I didn't include the whole file. You can see it here: https://github.com/inorganik/countUp.js/blob/master/dist/countUp.js

Comment: Line 13: `Object.definePropert(exports, ...)` — if `exports` is not defined, that's an exception.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn the point is I'm constrained to commonjs. I need to know if it's possible with commonjs or not. Thanks.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn - where exactly does MDN (or the spec) say ES6 module _import_ can import from a commonjs module?

Comment: @inorganik - it is not.

Comment: @Pointy indeed, and that may be a dealbreaker. Just trying to determine if there's any way es6 imports and commonjs can play nice together.

Comment: You can use a module loader, but not natively with ES6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short Answer: No

---

When using es6, you need to export using `export` and not `exports`. `exports` is a commonjs feature primarily used within node and not a web browser.

If you would like to use `commonjs` you need to use a third party library like [requirejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/requirejs), but this uses `require()` and not `import`, and `exports` and not `export`. You will then be able to write your code using import/export with typescript but it will be compiled using `require` and `requirejs` will handle the rest.

So, to use it in the browser properly, you would do it like so:

**test.js**

```
export function Test() {
  console.log('hello')
}
```

**index.js**

```
import { Test } from './test.js'
Test()
```

Then when you load the file in your html, the function test will execute.

```
<script src="index.js" type="module"></script>
```

Comment: So the answer to the OP's question is simply: NO.

Comment: I think your answer is no. Maybe you could reword it. Because the entire purpose of the question is to use commonjs. I can't change how it's exported.

Comment: It's worth clearing up (what seems to be) the OP's mixing-up terminology. OP title asks *"Is it possible to es6 `import` a commonjs module?"*, to which the answer is: Depends on *where* the import is done. If it's in Node.js, then [yes, it's possible](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#packages_determining_module_system), but if it's in the browser (which is what the OP refer to in the question body), then no, as you elaborate.

Comment: Imagine cjs=>esm `rollup api` `import { generate } from 'astring'; export class DurableObjectExample {constructor(el, env){ this.el = el; this.env = env; this.el.blockConcurrencyWhile(async()=> { let stored = await this.el.storage.get("esm"); watcher.on("event", (event) => { const ast = event.result.cache.modules.ast; const esm = generate(ast); this.el.storage.put("esm", JSON.stringify(esm)) });});}};` Like a programatic `global` namespace in an opinionated, read-only `self` v8 engine webworker, or a [durable object](https://github.com/NickCarducci/mastercard-backbank/blob/main/src/index.mjs)!

Comment: Why are people up-voting this answer if it does not answer the question? The question is obviously/directly/clearly asking if that is possible. If you need to change the commonjs code, that's not an answer anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Yes by using esm like this:

1. Install esm like

```
npm i -save esm
```

2. Run the app like

```
node -r esm filename.js
```

You can use import in cjs

Answer (score -2):

Actually you can use module.exports and import. It works with webpack, so does it with vs code