# Stability of mjs format and its usage in AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, aws-lambda, ecmascript-6

I am new to the Nodejs. I am using Lambda function with 18.x nodejs version and there I am using mjs file format for the ES6 syntax. I have doubt that if usage of mjs is stable or not in the AWS Lambda.

This may sound stupid but I am just worried that should I use the CommanJS(.js) or ES6 (.mjs) for the AWS Lambda

Comment: If anything goes away, it will be CommonJS, but that will be [in the future](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70691552/271415). I would say use MJS unless you cannot.